# Android - read file from internal storage public folder

Tags: android

In my application I am making for android, I want to add database import functionality. For that I have already designed import from web (MySql database via php script) and import from external storage (via CSV file).

Now I want to add option for importing via CSV from internal storage (for who doesn't have any external storage). So, can you please advice:

1) Whether this is advisable to add that option?
2) If it is, then how can I read file from public folders in internal storage?
3) Which folder should I target for that? Or I should just use the data folder for my applicatin?

Also, any other advice in this regard will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read data from internal storage you need your app files folder and read content from here :

```
File yourFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "File_Name.extension");
FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
```

Also you can use this approach :

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("hello.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line;
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line);
   }
```

Comment: Is it convenient for a user to put the CSV file in app files folder?